# C# FileNotFoundException, File name accessibility.properties

Tags: c#, filenotfoundexception

I have the following strange exception on my application,

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\MYUSER\.accessibility.properties'. File name:
>   'C:\Users\MYUSER\.accessibility.properties'    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

where I can find this file `accessibility.properties`

Comment: `.accessibility.properties` you have a point in the begin

Comment: Can you please post code?

Comment: Way more interesting would be to post the exception [*stack*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx), which would show you who is actually requesting this file.

Comment: @CodeFarmer , yes I know, and this is exactly what I get

Answer (score 0):

The system cannot find the file on that location.

Have you searched at C:\Users if there is the file "MYUSER.accessibility.properties"

My guess is you need to search at C:\Users\MYUSER\accessibility.properties (notice the \ after MYUSER).

Comment: Actually, There's no file called .accessibility.properties in MYUSER folder, and moreover, I don't know anything about this file.

Comment: why do you edit your stacktrace? - The error says that the system tries to open the file on that location. If you don't know anything about the file we need more information (like the code where it crashes)